# ELASTIC SEARCH initial heap size set to-a-larger-value-than-the-maximum-heap SIZE

Tags: java, php, elasticsearch, jvm

I have just downloaded elastic search.I run this commmand on the commmand:

`set ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xmx512m -Xms512m`
Then,
`elasticsearch.bat`

But I get this error:

```
C:\Users\PrimeJay\Downloads \elasticsearch-6.6.0\elasticsearch-6.6.0\bin>elastic
learch

Warning: ignoring JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m; pass JVM parameters via ES_JAVA_OPTS

Error occurred during initialization of VM;
Initial heap size set to a larger value than the maximum heap size
```

Comment: Not sure if this is a typo, but in `ES_JAVA_OPTS` you have `-Xmx` twice and no `-Xms`

Comment: @Val That might just be it!!!